# Does Matlab support exogenous variables in GARCH models?

Tags: time-series, garch, matlab, quantitative

Is it possible to introduce dummy variables or explanatory variables in the GARCH variance equation (`garchset` and `garchfit`) in Matlab?

This is done in the mean (ARMAX) equation through the input `Regress` in `garchset`, but I have not seen how it can be done for the variance equation as well. So how can I find a closed form solution to do it? I will appreciate any advice on the question.

Comment: I am not sure about Matlab but this is possible in R using package "rugarch". Use function `ugarchspec` and supply the exogenous regressors to the argument `external.regressors` inside the argument `variance.model`.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there is no public implementation in matlab. However both R and Ox have some packages devoted to this end :

-Ox - see [G@rch](http://www.oxmetrics.net/) package

-R  - see [rugarch](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/index.html) package